# Perl in calling methods

Tags: perl

Please tell me what does this mean

```
my ( $keepers, $bogus, $unknown ) =
   TCO::Test::Param::test_params('session' => $s, 'expected' => $allowed_params);
```

on test method

```
my %base_profile = TCO::Test::Param::std_profile();
my $profile      = {
    'session'  => $base_profile{'session'},
    'expected' => $base_profile{'params'},
};
my %config = validate( @_, $profile );

my ( $s, $gooduns ) = @config{ 'session', 'expected' };

my ( $keepers, $bogus, $unknown ) =
    scrub_base( 'raw_params' => $s->{_raw_params}, 'expected' => $gooduns );

foreach ( keys %{$keepers} ) {
    $keepers->{$_} = $keepers->{$_}->[-1];
}

clean_params( { 'params' => $keepers } );

# These are sometimes passed in by carts and must be squashed if they are.
delete $unknown->{x_exp_date} if ( $unknown->{x_exp_date} );

delete $unknown->{x_card_num} if ( $unknown->{x_card_num} );

delete $bogus->{x_exp_date}   if ( $bogus->{x_exp_date} );

delete $bogus->{x_card_num}   if ( $bogus->{x_card_num} );

delete $keepers->{x_exp_date} if ( $keepers->{x_exp_date} );

delete $keepers->{x_card_num} if ( $keepers->{x_card_num} );

return ( $keepers, $bogus, $unknown );
```

2) $sale->{state}{ind} = 0; what does this mean?

I tried to print `$keepers` to STDERR . then it gives a Hash. Can't i access the value in it. How can I access it. Please reply.

Answer (score 5):

> what does this mean

It's a call to subroutine `TCO::Test::Param::test_params`. Four arguments are passed to it. The first three values returned are stored in `$keepers`, `$bogus`, and `$unknown`.

---

> then it gives a Hash.

It's a reference to a hash. A sub can't return hashes, just a list of scalars.

---

> How can I access it.

```
keys(%$keepers)

$keepers->{$key}
```

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `TCO::Test::Param::test_params` subroutine returns a list. The line that you are asking about unpacks the return value into three different variables, `$keepers`, `$bogus`, and `$unknown`.

To see what is in `$keepers`, you can dump the hash:

```
use Data::Dumper;
warn Dumper( $keepers );
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is working. Can you tell me what does this mean 2) $sale->{state}{ind} = 0;

Answer (score 0):

Your question 2:

```
$sale->{state}{ind} = 0;
```

*what does this mean?*

`$sale` must be a reference to a hash.  Why?  Because it is followed by `->{ }`.  Try:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($sale);
```

The hash that `$sale` refers to has at least one key, called `state`.  The value of key `state` is a reference to another hash.  That other hash has at least one key, called `ind`, and the statement sets its value to zero.

This statement can be run even if the key `state` does not already exist.  The statement would create the key, and it's value, and the second hash, all automagically, in a process known as *autovivification*.

Suggestion:  only ask one question at a time.  It makes the answers clearer and easier for others to reference.  Just as a subroutine should only do one thing, so should your question, and for the same reasons.

Comment: But my problem is if {ind} is an hash then I can print it that value. But when i tried to print it as warn Dumper({ind}). on the error log it gives an error as '[error] Bareword "ind" not allowed while "strict subs" in use' . Please reply me. I am new to Perl

Comment: @user2089651: {ind} will just return a reference to a new anonymous hash.  Anyway, ind is just the name of a key.  You need `warn Dumper($sale->{state})`.